# Issue "TypeError: external_defu_ is not a function" running generate on gitlab

Tags: node.js, gitlab, nuxt.js

every time I try to launch the generate for my nuxt project on gitlab, I get back for every page generated a strange error,

```
[error]  /Dashboard
TypeError: external_defu_ is not a function
    at server.js:12669:45
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at new runtime_BaseScheme (node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next/dist/runtime.mjs:883:0)
    at new runtime_Oauth2Scheme (node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next/dist/runtime.mjs:1137:0)
    at auth (node_modules/.cache/nuxt/auth.js:45:0)
    at createApp (node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js:291:0)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
    at async module.exports.__webpack_exports__.default (node_modules/.cache/nuxt/server.js:85:0)
```

This prevents the page from generating itself correctly.
While if I launch the project locally, with the same version of node, it generates everything correctly.
Do you know how I can solve the problem?
In gitlab's docker I'm using node v12.16.3.
This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "xxx",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "xxx",
"author": "Alessandro",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"generate": "ENV=production nuxt generate",
generate",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ."
},
"dependencies": {
"@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
"@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1613647907.37b1156",
"@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
"@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.4",
"@vue/composition-api": "^0.6.7",
"aws-sdk": "^2.610.0",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"browser-image-compression": "^1.0.14",
"caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001257",
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"child_process": "^1.0.2",
"compass": "^0.1.1",
"cookie": "^0.4.0",
"cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
"install": "^0.13.0",
"js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
"kaleidoscopejs": "1.0.18",
"leaflet": "^1.6.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"moment": "^2.29.3",
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"net": "^1.0.2",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
"node-orientdb-http": "^0.1.1",
"npm": "^8.13.1",
"nuxt": "^2.15.0",
"nuxt-gmaps": "^1.2.10",
"nuxt-i18n": "^6.3.0",
"nuxt-leaflet": "0.0.19",
"nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.5",
"p-iteration": "^1.1.8",
"pannellum": "github:saidmoya12/pannellum",
"panolens": "^0.12.1",
"proxy": "^1.0.2",
"readline": "^1.3.0",
"simple-analytics-vue": "^1.1.5",
"tls": "0.0.1",
"videojs": "^1.0.0",
"videojs-panorama": "^0.1.7",
"vue": "2.6.14",
"vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
"vue-cookie-accept-decline": "^5.3.1",
"vue-expandable-image": "^0.1.0",
"vue-google-login": "^2.0.3",
"vue-pannellum": "^0.5.3",
"vue-plausible": "^1.2.1",
"vue-rangedate-picker": "^1.0.0",
"vue-rangedate-picker-winslow": "^1.0.8",
"vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.12",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
"vue-tooltipster": "^1.2.0",
"vue-upload-multiple-image": "^1.1.4",
"vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
"vue2-leaflet": "^2.6.0",
"vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
"vuejs-panorama": "^1.1.9",
"vuejs-vr": "^1.2.2",
"vuetify": "^2.5.12",
"vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.45.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@aceforth/nuxt-optimized-images": "^1.4.0",
"@nuxt/bridge": "npm:@nuxt/bridge-edge@^3.0.0-27268729.5b8e10f",
"@nuxt/image": "^0.7.1",
"@nuxt/types": "^2.14.12",
"@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
"@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
"@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
"@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.4.0",
"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"eslint": "^7.5.0",
"eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
"imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
"imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
"imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.2",
"imagemin-svgo": "^9.0.0",
"lqip-loader": "^2.2.1",
"responsive-loader": "^2.3.0",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2",
"sharp": "^0.30.7",
"sqip-loader": "^1.0.0",
"webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
}
}
```

Thank you very much
Alessandro

Comment: So, with the same node version on both sides (gitlab and locally), it's fails to generate?

Comment: Maybe give this one a try: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4296#issuecomment-1096778433

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue on Nuxt2 Bridge using `@nuxtjs/auth-next`. The solution is to transpile `defu` during the build:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...

  build: {
    transpile: [
      'defu',
    ],
  },
})
```

The issue and possible solutions are described in the docs: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/esm/

Comment: thank you - it did help.. i got this problem in next/auth with nuxt2